# How can I right justify format a string while pasting in R?

Tags: r, string, format

I have a file that I am reading in a loop where I need to replace a certain variable.

```
ptl <- readLines("template.txt") %>% 
  gsub(pattern = "TEMPNUM", replace = format(testval) %>% 
  write.table(., paste0("test.txt"), row.names=F, col.names=F, quote = F)
```

The testval will change in every loop, but I want it to be right justified.

Here, the concerned line looks like this:

```
F 0     0.000   -10.000    10.000 .10   1.0 0 0 0 99 0 0 
T 0   TEMPNUM     1.000     1.001 .10   1.0 0 3 1  0 3 0
```

Now, obviously, the final file looks like this:

```
F 0     0.000   -10.000    10.000 .10   1.0 0 0 0 99 0 0 
T 0  1.0005     1.000     1.001 .10   1.0 0 3 1  0 3 0
```

## Expected outcome

```
F 0     0.000   -10.000    10.000 .10   1.0 0 0 0 99 0 0 
T 0    1.0005     1.000     1.001 .10   1.0 0 3 1  0 3 0
```

## Tried

- `replace = format(val[1,2]), justify="right")`

**P.S.**

The length of `T 0   TEMPNUM` is 13 characters and fixed in all my files. if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

On option is to use `write.fwf` function from `gdata` package. I have used the data presented by OP to create a data.frame which I tried writing to file.

```
library(dplyr)
library(gdata)

df %>% mutate(V3 = gsub(pattern = "TEMPNUM", replace = format(1.05), V3)) %>%
  write.fwf(., paste0("d:\\test.txt"), colnames = FALSE, justify="right", quote = FALSE)
```

Content of the file is:

```
FALSE 0 0.000 -10 10.000 0.1 1 0 0 0 99 0 0
 TRUE 0  1.05   1  1.001 0.1 1 0 3 1  0 3 0
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"F 0     0.000   -10.000    10.000 .10   1.0 0 0 0 99 0 0 
T 0   TEMPNUM     1.000     1.001 .10   1.0 0 3 1  0 3 0",
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I wish there were a base R solution. But let me try this one. Thanks!

Comment: Ah - I didn't want to justify all the numbers, *JUST TEMPNUM*. This is a very long text, and some of them actually have to be left justified too. Sorry for the miscommunication. I am trying just TEMPNUM, and not the whole line.